# anchors all link to one point

Tags: html, wordpress-theming, anchor, zurb-foundation

I am using anchors in my wordpress child theme, the base theme uses a Zurb Foundation Grid.

I am simply using the standard anchor code;

```
<a name="anchor">
```

and

```
<a href="#anchor">
```

Someone told me that the 'name' thing doesn't work in wordpress and you should use ID, but this still gives me the same result. I have three different anchors but they all get directed to the same spot on the page, even though the names are different and all the tags are nicely closed. Why is this happening? This never happened to me before and hours of googling could not solve my problem.

This is my full html code of the homepage, with the anchors in it.

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Homepage
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

            <div id="content" class="twelve columns">

                <div id="main" role="main">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[orbit-slider]') ?>
                </div> <!-- end #main -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="nine columns">
                    </div>
                    <div id="logoblock" class="three columns">
                        <img src="http://i44.tinypic.com/2pyw3sl.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end #content -->


                <div class="row buttonbar">
                <div class="twelve columns rowmargintop">
                    <div id="downloads" class="four columns"><a href="#downloads">
                        <img src="http://i39.tinypic.com/2v3j8na.png">
                        <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Downloads Button Homepage') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
                    </a></div>
                    <div id="locator" class="four columns"><a href="#locator">
                        <img src="http://i42.tinypic.com/25zgdwj.png">
                        <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Locator Button Homepage') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>

                    </a></div>
                    <div id="specials" class="four columns"><a href="#specials">
                        <img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/16101l1.png">
                        <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Specials Button Homepage') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>

                    </a></div>
                </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row rowmargin">
                    <div class="twelve columns">
                        <div class="twelve columns downloadbg">
                        <a id="downloads">
                        <div class="four columns downloadcontent">
                        <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Download Left') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>

                        </div></a>                      <div class="four columns downloadcontent">
                        <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Download Mid') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>

                        </div>
                        <div class="four columns downloadcontent">
                        <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Download Right') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>


                        <div class="twelve columns downloadbg emailmargin">
                        <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Email Me') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row rowmargin">
                    <div class="twelve columns">
                    <div class="twelve columns">
                    <div class="twelve columns locatorcontent">
                    <a id="locator">
                    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Store Locator') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?></a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row"><a id="specials">
                <div class="twelve columns rowmargin">
                <div class="twelve columns">
                    <div class="twelve columns">
                    <div class="twelve columns specialcontent specialstop">
                        <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Specials Top Content') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="twelve columns">
                    <div class="twelve columns specialcontent">
                        <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Specials Bottom Content') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div></a>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- end twelve columns -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And I uploaded the full code of the page when I open it (it's local atm) and use 'show page source', hoping I could give you guys some more info. http://codepad.org/J9OEq49f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the id #locator from your wrapper.

```
<div id="locator" class="four columns"><a href="#locator">
```

Also, don't ever use more than one id with the same name on a page. It breaks your code.
That's the problem here. You got multiple id's with the same name. He will fixate on your wrapper instead of your content block down the code.

Note: As you already mentioned, you can also use the name attribute instead of an id attribute.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't spot the double name, thank you for helping!

Comment: The devil in in the details ;)